# Debugging in Pact provider verification

Tags: javascript, pact

I am currently trying to verify pacts and the response body does not match in provider tests.

I get the below error

`JSON::ParserError:757: unexpected token at 'null'`

I get back the correct request via Postman. Is there anyway I can check the outgoing request and the incoming response?

I tried setting `logLevel` to `Debug`, but it does not provide the expected data.

```
if("validates the expectations of api", async function () {
    let opts = {
        provider: "consumer",
        logLevel: "DEBUG",
        verbose: true,
        enablePending: true,
        providerBaseUrl: "http://10.54.12.223:8083",
        pactUrls: [
          path.resolve(process.cwd(), "./pacts/<name>.json")
        ],
        providerVersion: "1.0.0"
    }

    return new Verifier(opts).verifyProvider().then(output => {
        console.log("Verification complete!");
    }

})
```

Comment: Can you please add more context - is this a consumer or provider test? Showing your actual code example would be great. Pact often has other output/logs, please also share that.

Comment: I have added the code for provider tests. I am trying to print out the request and response to the logs.

Comment: The tests are running on a different machine which is very secure and getting the logs out without sensitive data is a bit of work. Let me know if you absolutely need them

Answer (score 0):

Without the response body, it's going to be hard to diagnose. The pact file might be useful, but I suspect it's the response body that is incorrect. Likely, your code is not returning valid JSON. See a similar error at https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-net/issues/139.

You would get this issue if the response type is `application/json` and the body is not valid JSON.

What version of Pact Node are you using? There was an issue in old versions of Pact that wouldn't allow a top level string or `null` (see above issue).

Comment: Yes, that is why I am trying to print out the response from the provider requests. Is there any variable I can set in the provider setup to achieve this?

Comment: I'm looking to add request/response (see https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/pull/462) but for now, you'll need to add logs to your provider itself.